# Hue and Apache Ranger on Hdp cluster

Tags: hortonworks-data-platform, hue, apache-ranger

I have Hue working on a Hortonworks Data Platform cluster. Since I cannot use Sentry for a HDP platform, I want to make use of Apache Ranger to enable security and other benefits. So, can I use Apache Ranger along with Hue?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Hue normally, it is Hadoop not Hue who applies the Ranger or Sentry permissions so all should work normally (just Ranger might require the impersonation to be on or off like Sentry).

Comment: Okay. Thanks a lot:)